# How to merge two data frames with same column names but columns in different order

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I have two datasets with columns that have same name but different order. How could I merge these to a new dataset where the columns named the same would have been merged.

I have tried:

```
data1 <- read.csv2("Data2 kopio 2.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data2 <- read.csv2("Data3.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

common_column_names <- intersect(names(data1), names(data2))


data3 <- merge(data1, data2, by=common_column_names, all.data1=TRUE)
```

But the result is a empty data frame with 0 observations and 375 variables.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: I would expect this approach to work. Can you share `data1` and `data2` using `dput()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think just replacing `all.data1=TRUE` with `all.x=TRUE` will work well.
By the way, please be careful that, when you use `all.x=TRUE`, rows in `data2` that do not exist in `data1` will not be preserved in `data3`. If you want to preserve all rows in both `data1` and `data2`, `all=TRUE` will do the job.
I hope this will help!